# Custom XAML property

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I've seen a library that allows me to do this inside my XAML, which sets the visibility of the control based on whether or not the user is in a role:
s:Authorization.RequiresRole="Admin"

Using that library with my database requires a bunch of coding that I can't really do right now. Ultimately here's what I want to know...

I have received the authenticated users role from my SPROC, and its currently stored in my App.xaml.cs as a property (not necessary for the final solution, just FYI for now). I want to create a property (dependency property? attached property?) that allows me to say something very similar to what the other library has: RequiresRole="Admin", which would collapse the visibility if the user is not in the Admin role. Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

**EDIT**
After building the authorization class, I get the following error: 
"The property 'RequiredRole' does not exist on the type 'HyperlinkButton' in the XML Namespace clr-namespace:TSMVVM.Authorization"

I'm trying to add this xaml:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="lnkSiteParameterDefinitions" 
        Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
                                  Tag="SiteParameterDefinitions" 
        Content="Site Parameter Definitions" 
        Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
        s:Authorization.RequiredRole="Admin"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, ElementName=lnkSiteParameterDefinitions}"/>
```

When I started typing the s:Authorization.RequiredRole="Admin", intellisense picked it up. I tried setting the typeof(string) and typeof(ownerclass) to HyperlinkButton to see if that would help, but it didn't. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attached property is the way to implement it. You should define a property like this:

```
public class Authorization
{
    #region Attached DP registration

    public static string GetRequiredRole(UIElement obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(RequiredRoleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRequiredRole(UIElement obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RequiredRoleProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RequiredRole.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RequiredRoleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RequiredRole", typeof(string), typeof(Authorization), new PropertyMetadata(RequiredRole_Callback));

    // This callback will be invoked when some control will receive a value for your 'RequiredRole' property
    private static void RequiredRole_Callback(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = (UIElement) source;
        RecalculateControlVisibility(uiElement);

        // also this class should subscribe somehow to role changes and update all control's visibility after role being changed
    }

    private static void RecalculateControlVisibility(UIElement control)
    {
        //Authorization.UserHasRole() - is your code to check roles
        if (Authentication.UserHasRole(GetRequiredRole(control)))
            control.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else 
            control.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

PS: Have noticed too late that you were asking about Silverlight. Though I believe it works in the same way there, but I've tried it only on WPF.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This looks great, but I have a few questions about implementation..
1) typeof(ownerclass) - I set this to Authorization, but I'm not sure if this is right.

2) new UIPropertyMetadata ... is this the same as new PropertyMetadata? UIPropertyMetadata isn't resolving for me.

3) I created the UserHasRole method and simply returned true if App.Role.ToLower() is the same as the passed-in role.ToLower(). Sound right?

4) added an edit to my OP, as I got an error when building.

Comment: @Scott ownerClass - 1) Authorization, i edited it in my answer. 2) Yes, Silverlight doesn't have UIPropertyMetadata available, it's ok to use PropertyMetadata 3) yes

Comment: any idea why I'm getting the error I added to my original post?

Comment: The error isn't there after coming back from the gym and dinner. I had definitely rebuilt prior, but maybe I did or didn't do something else. Still another issue with getting this to work (its comparing roles before the user has logged on) but I'll ask another question for that. Thanks Snowbear!